# Add edits to .git/config to the origin repo

Tags: git, github

I edited my local repository so that when I push to the `master` branch it will also push to the `gh-pages`.

My local `.git/commit` contains this line in it.

```
push = +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/gh-pages
push = +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

I would like it so that if I cloned this repo the `.git/commit` still has the above lines in `.git/commit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right out of the box using git, this isn't possible right now. You can't share configuration on pull/push/clone right now (which could sometime be useful I have to admit).

So, the best solution in this case would be to share your repo using tar/zip rather than git clone. This way you can include the `.git` folder.

Otherwise, you could use and share a bash script to automatically setup git repo as needed.